# How can I create a new menu item that links to an archive of a custom post type?

Tags: menus, archives, custom-post-type-archives, add-menu-page

I have a function that programmatically creates menu items in Wordpress. I am able to create menu items to individual pages and posts, but how can I create a menu item for a custom post type archive? Specifically, what are the arguments passed to wp_update_nav_menu_item()?

```
$args = []; // what goes in this array?

wp_update_nav_menu_item($menuID, 0, $args);
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching through the core Wordpress files, I found the necessary arguments. The key is setting `menu-item-object` to be the slug of your post type and the `menu-item-type` to be `post_type_archive`.

```
$args = [
    'menu-item-position' => $position,
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
    'menu-item-parent-id' => 0,
    'menu-item-object' => 'my-post-type',
    'menu-item-type' => 'post_type_archive'
];

wp_update_nav_menu_item($menuID, 0, $args);
```